# Unable to locate HTML element source

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup, python-requests

If you navigate to the following [URL](https://app.bancor.network/eth/protection/stake/add/single/0xCDfF066eDf8a770E9b6A7aE12F7CFD3DbA0011B5) and select `BNT` from the `Stake Amount` menu.

Then you will notice a 2 values that keep displaying with auto-refresh.

[image]

am trying to figure out from where those values loaded.

I noticed the following `XHR` request to the following [API](https://api-v2.bancor.network/welcome) which loads `JSON` data. but I am unable to get the values yet.

I think that it might be an internal mathematical equation done for the value!

May someone has a clue towards that?

Comment: Looks like the page is written in vue, so can't scrape it and that data is coming form an xhr request every few seconds

Comment: I think it is summarizing some data from `/welcome`

Comment: Looks like the calculation takes place in this function: https://github.com/bancorprotocol/webapp/blob/44ba23bf3cea5537b8ff5e3120efa1a072beb74c/src/store/modules/swap/ethBancor.ts#L3702

Comment: @TenaciousB thank you. but am still unsure how to get it?